# unexpected token error when comparing two strings

Tags: javascript

I'm going through the existing scripts on the page and comparing them to one i'm about to load to see if it is is already loaded. If it is loaded then I will call a function that uses it. If not then I will load it and call a function that is using it.

However, I'm getting an `unexpected token` error whether I use `==` or `===` for the comparison of the existing script tag's attribute to the src value I want to add.

What am I doing wrong that is causing the error?

```
function isScriptAlreadyIncluded(src){
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
    for(var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++){
        if(scripts[i].getAttribute('src')) == src) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
if(isScriptAlreadyIncluded('contextualConversation.js')) contextualReplace();
else{
    var cCScript = document.createElement('script');
    cCScript.src = 'contextualConversation.js';
    contextualReplace();
}
```

Comment: Your parentheses aren't balanced.

Comment: You need a better IDE if it doesn't catch trivial syntax errors like this.

Comment: There's no need for *getAttribute*, `scripts[i].src` is less to type. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an extra paren in your comparison line.

Updated:

```
if(scripts[i].getAttribute('src') == src) return true;
```

Original:

```
if(scripts[i].getAttribute('src')) == src) return true;
```